# Cordova geolocation doesn't work in some mobile devices

Tags: cordova, geolocation

I am using cordova geolocation plugin in my mobile application and in the recent days, some mobile devices doesn't give the location even with high timeout interval being set. Even setting the accuracy to low also doesn't work. Any suggestion for this issue?

```
logCurrentLocation() {
    let maximumAge = 0;
    let enableHighAccuracy = true;
    const navigatorObj: any = navigator;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      
    }, { maximumAge: maximumAge, timeout: 60000, enableHighAccuracy: enableHighAccuracy });
  }
```

Can someone help me in finding a solution on how to get the user location in the mobile

Comment: Add an error callback and see what it says

Comment: @Eric, Even the call back is not getting invoked. We see issues most on Android 10 version.